# Calcular existencia

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando un modulo que me diga el numero de plantillas que me han entregado de un total de 100.

Quiero que al ingresar un numero en `ENTREGADAS` me reste en `NO_ENTREGADAS` que vale 100, es decir:

Ejemplo:
 - si `ENTREGADAS` vale 0, `NO_ENTREGADAS` va a quedar 100
 - si `ENTREGADAS= 25`, `NO_ENTREGADAS= 75`; 
 - `ENTREGADAS= 99`, `NO_ENTREGADAS= 1`

Hasta ahora tengo algo asi:

```js
function entregaplanillas() {

  if (document.form1.ENTREGADAS.value = 0) {
    document.form1.NO_ENTREGADAS.value = 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id=" ENTREGADAS " type="number" onblur="entregaplanillas();"></input>
<input id=" NO_ENTREGADAS " type="number"></input>
```

Comment: Lo estas realizando? y que llevas de esto, ¿Cual es el problema aquí?

Comment: Por favor, añade el HTML y JS para poder ayudarte sobre tu codigo.

Comment: Si no muestras tu problema sera difícil que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Es que en realidad no se como representarlo, pero estaba pensando en algo como:

    if(document.form1.ENTREGADAS.value = 0){
    document.form1.NO_ENTREGADAS.value = 100;
    }

Comment: Pues has de intentar algo.. no te lo podemos hacer por ti. Cuando lo intentes muestranos tu codigo con sus fallos o problemas concretos

Comment: @AnderssonViverosMartinez Estimado, necesitas mostrar el resultado en input 2 mientras ingresas datos en input1? o al momento de presionar un boton?

Comment: Pido disculpas a todos, pero soy nuevo en todo esto, y lo que quiero es mostrar el resultado en el input "NO_ENTREGADAS", es decir que con solo ingresar un numero en "ENTREGADAS", me muestre el numero de planillas que faltan por entregar en "NO_ENTREGADAS"

Comment: @AnderssonViverosMartinez , tambien puedes embeber codigo html-javascript-css para probarlo directo de stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un ejemplo basico, pero espero que cojas la idea

```js
amount = document.getElementById("amount");

total = document.getElementById("total");


amount.onchange = function(e) {
  total.value = 100 - parseInt(amount.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="amount" type="number" value="0"></input>
<input id="total" type="number" value="100"></input>
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia. No deberias solucionarle el problema ya que ni el autor muestra lo que ha intentado. Espera que lo edite para publicar tu respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Ok, entonces elimino mi respuesta y la subo despues?

Comment: Si, luego tendrás un boton de "recuperar" . Y añade comprobacion para que si pones 110, no aparezca "-10" en input 2

Comment: Seria fijar el maximo del input a 100

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya lo solucione, por si a alguien le sirve el codigo quedo asi:

```
function entregaplanillas(){

entregadas = document.getElementById("ENTREGADAS");
sinentregar = document.getElementById("NO_ENTREGADAS");

entregadas.onchange = function(e) {
sinentregar.value = 100 - parseInt(entregadas.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Y en que se diferencia esta de mi solucion ??

Comment: Listo ya acepte tu respuesta. ese día quitaste la pregunta, y con lo que medio alcance a ver hice la solución, por eso subí la respuesta yo mismo.

Comment: no problem, solo que me llego la notificacion y vi -15 :(

Answer (score 0):

Usando jquery..... al evento que sucede despues de presionar una tecla y soltarla
hay que colocar el input de tipo de dato numeric para no tener que hacer la validacion con js que sea numero

```js
$(document).on("ready", function(e) {

  $("#input1").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var input2;
    if ($("#input1").val() !== "") {

      var input1 = $(this).val();

      input2 = 100 - input1;
    } else {
      input2 = 0;
    }

    $("#input2").val("Entregado " + input2 + " de 100");


  });
});
```

```html
<body>

  <p>Cantidad Entregada</p>

  <input id="input1" pattern="[0-9]" type="number">
  <p>Entregado a Fecha</p>
  <input id="input2" type="text">

</body>
```